# Inequality related with e number

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

In a number theory paper I saw such inequality:

For any $t>0,$ $(1+\frac{1}{t})^{t+\frac{1}{2}} > e$.

How to prove it? It is obvious for $t \geq 1$ but how to prove for arbitrarily small $t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $t>0$,
\begin{align*}
\left( {t + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{t}} \right) &= (2t + 1)\tanh ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{1}{{2t + 1}}} \right) \\ & = 1 + \frac{1}{{3(2t + 1)^2 }} + \frac{1}{{5(2t + 1)^4 }} +  \cdots  > 1.
\end{align*}
Taking the exponential of each side yields the required inequality.

Comment: Yeah I see it was quite easy. I just don't have relation between logarithm and tanh all the time in memory.